# why mySQL data export hang inbetween?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, mysql

I do have 1 million datas in my MySQL database and when I export whole data it is getting stuck in between and showing the download box for long time. sometimes it will export without any issues. but if I do multiple table exports then couple of tables may export and others are getting stuck. why is this happening and what will be the work around for the same??

well I am using PhpMyadmin to export

Answer (score 2):

It is most likely due to the data size. The webserver could have timeout issues or run out of memory when exporting big amounts of data.

I suggest exporting one table at a time with phpMyAdmin  (in SQL format, avoid using XLS), but if it still fails, you may consider using [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html).

Answer (score 1):

What you do is, delete phpmyadmin from your system, write to the developers, and tell them to immediately discontinue development and destory all copies of the source.

You get everyone who has ever installed phpmyadmin to delete their copies too, and then *bing* the world will be a better place...

It is alas, but a dream.

PHPMyAdmin is a wart on the arse of the universe and should be eliminated; it is a kind of fungus which poisons any data it touches with a painful, lingering death.

Moreover, the developers appear keen to insist that it is actually *useful*; it has an interface which makes things which fail appear to work, thus fooling the naive user into believing that it has actually DONE what it was asked to do.

Its backups give an overwhelmingly false sense of security; they cannot be considered to be "backups" insofar as one might hope to restore them.